# Persist button state in a cookie or localStorage in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to persist a button state in a cookie for a certain amount of time using either cookies (cookie.js library) or LocalStorage. I have not done this before so I am not sure how I can approach it.

The state I want to persist for at least a day would be changing the button's text using Jquery text function as follows:

```
$(_this).text("Job already started or completed...");
```

This action would pretty much be done on an onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is vanilla JS, it works with or without jQuery. It's fairly simple:

```
localStorage.setItem('buttonText', 'Job already started or completed...');
```

That stores it. Then to read it:

```
const storedButtonText = localStorage.getItem('buttonText');
```

From there you can do whatever you want with that text, including passing it into a jQuery function to set some DOM element's text or whatever else you want.

You will want to load that data on page load if you want to persist across reloads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const storedButtonText = localStorage.getItem('buttonText');
    if (storedButtonText) {
        $('#theButtonElement').text("Job already started or completed...");
    }
});
```

Comment: In fact, I already tried that. The problem is I do have this state change bound to a click event. So even when I reload the page, the button returns back to its original state regardless.

Comment: It looks like not just the text that is lost, but the whole action: (_this).text("Job already started or completed...");

Comment: Well, yeah; reloading the page reloads everything back to its initial state. To persist state across reloads, you need to add code that runs when the page loads and pulls the state from localStorage. There's no way to automatically do that, you have to code it to do that. (Alternatively, you can store the state server-side, but your question sounded like you want a client-side solution.)

Comment: I know I am still trying to figure out the best approach to do it.

Comment: You just do the same thing but on page load... I edited a simple example into this answer for you.

Comment: I already got it to work with both Jquery and LocalStorage. The issue is when I check on page reload and then assign the text to the button, it affects all the generated buttons that have the same class name. It does not look like there is a way to remember the last clicked button as we do with the this keyword and siblings...

Comment: Ah, I see now. No, the reference to `this` only exists inside a specific scope. When the page reloads, you lose all scope. If you want to load a state to a specific button, you need some way of targeting just that button after a page reload, which means it'll need a unique ID, class, or other unique identifier. I'd suggest giving each button an ID and using that.